# jUpgrade stuck during downloading Joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla

I migrated Joomla 1.0 to Joomla 1.5.26 and install jUpgrade component to migrate to joomla 2.5.4 but jUpgrade stuck during downloading Joomla 2.5.

What is the problem...?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a fault in the component, you probably lost internet connection for a bit or there was a server glicth. Just try again and it wil most likely work

Answer (score 4):

jUpgrade is rather notorious for having all kinds of glitches and problems.

One easy, simple way to get past a downloading problem is to download the version of Joomla you want directly from Joomla's site, extract it into jUpgrade's target folder for your soon-to-be-migrated site, and then change jUpgrade's settings to skip the download process:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was expirenced with this problem.

For this first simply check:
1) your internet connection.
2) do not reload or navigate from there.
3) internet speed may required.

now if you stuck since long time, then try it frequently it may be success at once.
i has same situation to use this component and after some try i have succeed.

Try it may be its helps you.